# Multiple list creation (R)

Tags: r, list

I'm stuck with a problem from 2 days now...

I have this simple list :

```
comp=list("ABN","WT","N")
```

And I want to create this multiple list :

```
comp=list(c("ABN","WT"),c("ABN","N"),c("WT","N"))
```

It's like a cartesian product but in a unique list.

I already tryed many code and search for packages but don't find anything.

Ths for help !

Answer (score 2):

You can use `combn`.

```
combn(x=unlist(comp),m=2,simplify=FALSE)
```